# How can I define a unique field in lucid orm in adonisjs latest app?

Tags: mysql, adonis.js, lucid

import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
import { withAuthFinder } from '@adonisjs/auth'
import hash from '@adonisjs/core/services/hash'
import { compose } from '@adonisjs/core/helpers'
import { BaseModel, column } from '@adonisjs/lucid/orm'

const AuthFinder = withAuthFinder(() => hash.use('scrypt'), {
uids: ['phone'],
passwordColumnName: 'password',
})

export default class User extends compose(BaseModel, AuthFinder) {
@column({ isPrimary: true })
declare id: number

@column()
declare fullName: string | null

@column()
declare email: string

*// I want to create this phone field unique and give it length to max=10 and min 10*
@column()
declare phone: string

@column()
declare password: string

@column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true })
declare createdAt: DateTime

@column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true, autoUpdate: true })
declare updatedAt: DateTime | null
}

I have tried like this but I'm getting error.

@column({
** unique: true**
})
declare phone: string

and I modify it a little bit to see if it works but it didn't

@column(
** unique: true**
)
declare phone: string